# How to force label line break using Django-crispy-forms

Tags: python, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-crispy-forms

I have the following django scheme:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout, Field

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name_param        = forms.CharField()
    email_param       = forms.EmailField()
    message_param     = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    captcha_div = "<div class=\"g-recaptcha\" data-sitekey=\"xxxxxoBjAnlYtR\"></div> <br>"

    class Meta:
        pass
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Forms for contact.
        """
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-contactForm'
        self.helper.form_class =  'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.fields['name_param'].label = "Name"
        self.fields['email_param'].label = "Email"
        self.fields['message_param'].label = "Message"
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('name_param'),
            Field('email_param'),
            Field('message_param'),
            HTML(self.captcha_div),
          )

        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
```

My question is

[image: How to make the labels on top of their respective fields permanently?]

So that even if I resize the browser they will stick on the top of their respective fields.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML and CSS used to render the form may be defined by a [template pack](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#template-packs) and a [layout](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html). By default when you don't specify anything, crispy-forms uses the bootstrap template pack and the default layout. From what I can see, you are using the bootstrap3 template pack with the default layout. In that case you can do some basic alterations of the display using [attributes of the FormHelper](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/form_helper.html#bootstrap-helper-attributes).

In fact this is what you are doing when setting these attributes:

```
    self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
    self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
```

With these two instructions you are saying that all labels should have the CSS class `col-lg-2` and all fields should have the form `col-lg-8`. This is why the labels are on the left of the fields and take respectively 1/6<sup>th</sup> and 4/6<sup>th</sup> of the view (if you are using a 12 columns grid). 
Since you want the labels and fields on separate lines, you can simply give a CSS class that takes the whole view width:

```
    self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-12'
    self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-12'
```

Note that if you want something responsive, you can leverage the power of the bootstrap grid. For example if you want fields on the same line as labels on large screens, and below labels on small screen, you could do:

```
    self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-4'
    self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-8'
```

You can even give several CSS classes to the field.